# Adding a string to start of one column

Tags: r

I have this dataframe

```
> head(mut)
  sample chr     pos ref alt
1  t_005   1  928006   G   A
2  t_005   1 1649842   G   T
3  t_005   1 2020408   G   A
4  t_005   1 2031677   T   A
5  t_005   1 2901878   G   A
6  t_005   1 3039338   G   A
>
```

How I can add `"chr"` to the `chr` column? I mean, instead of `"1"` I want `"chr1"`, etc.

Comment: This is basic R question and more suitable to StackOverflow main site, and it is already has been asked many times, see [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24055308/680068)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
mut$chr <- paste("chr", mut$chr, sep = "")
```

Comment: if you use *paste0* instead of *paste*, you can omit the 'sep=""'